# php random link from array

Tags: php

```
<? 
    $urls = array(
    array(
        'http://cur.lv/xlnc',
        'http://cur.lv/xln8',
        'http://cur.lv/xln5',
        'http://cur.lv/xln4',
        'http://cur.lv/xlmv',
        'http://cur.lv/xlms',
        'http://cur.lv/xllz',
        'http://cur.lv/xllp',
        'http://cur.lv/xllj',
        'http://cur.lv/xlle',
        'http://cur.lv/xll9',
        'http://cur.lv/xll5',
        'http://cur.lv/xlks',
        'http://cur.lv/xlkl',
        'http://cur.lv/xlke',
        'http://cur.lv/xlk4',
        'http://cur.lv/xljv',
        'http://cur.lv/xlje',
        'http://cur.lv/xlj9',
        'http://cur.lv/xlj1',
        'http://cur.lv/xjxu',
        'http://cur.lv/xjxd',
        'http://cur.lv/xjx4',
        'http://cur.lv/xjwz',
        'http://cur.lv/xjw1',
        'http://cur.lv/xjup',
        'http://cur.lv/xjtz',
        'http://cur.lv/xjtt',
        'http://cur.lv/xjtn',
        'http://cur.lv/xjrh',
        'http://cur.lv/xjrd',
        'http://cur.lv/xjr3',
        'http://cur.lv/xj1z',
        'http://cur.lv/xizx',
        'http://cur.lv/xizf',
        'http://cur.lv/x3jx',
        'http://cur.lv/x3jp'
    )
);

$randomlink = array_rand($urls, 1);
$thelink = $randomlink[0];
echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $thelink . '">Random Faucet</a>'
?>
```

doesn't seem to work trying to get it to display one of those links randomly every click..

Comment: Your PHP runs on the web server once, before the browser gets the page. The random selection therefore occurs once, before the browser gets the page. So then when your page is displayed in the browser the link will always open that same particular link on every click, until you refresh the page and call the PHP code again.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're making a 2D array?

Comment: so if i look into ajax i would be able to make it refresh on click couldn't i? :) http://allaboutbit.com/demo/ trying to make a random faucet button.. is all

Comment: This could be done in JavaScript if you want it to change every click

Comment: I posted a JavaScript example that will change the `href` on every click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
 $thelink = $randomlink[0];
```

to

```
$thelink = $urls[$randomlink];
```

---

```
$randomlink = array_rand($urls, 1)
```

Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries

Answer (score 1):

`$randomlink` contains the array key, so you would use: `$thelink = $urls[$randomlink]`. See [`array_rand()` on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Answer (score 0):

`array_rand` returns the **keys** of the entries, not the entires themselves.

Here's an example from the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

So in your case you probably want `$thelink = $urls[$randomlink[0]];`